# float with array of structures?

Tags: c

I am getting a runtime error while running the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct emp
    {
        char name[20];
        float sal;
    };
    struct emp e[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
        scanf("%s %f", e[i].name, &e[i].sal);
    return 0;
}
```

Runtime error is *floating point formats not linked.*
some body please help me to run this program.

Comment: compiles fine on gcc 4.8.2

Comment: Are you using Turbo-C?

Comment: yes I am using turbo-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following anywhere outside `main` after all the includes.

```
void dummy(float *a) {
float b=*a; //perform some floating access
dummy (&b); //calling a floating point function
}
```

You need not call this function